# how to replace token in ${} by velocity

Tags: token, velocity

I want to replace token ${artifactId} by velocity. But as you could see, it's included in another ${} block.
So velocity throw parse exception. 
My question is how to handle this case? I have to remain ${jsp.related.[...].Sample.welcome} block for another usage.

```
<div class="title">${jsp.related.${artifactId}.Sample.welcome}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#set( $startbrace = "${" )
#set( $endbrace = "}" )
<div class="title">${startbrace}res.content.global.${artifactId}.Sample.welcome${endbrace}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="title">#evaluate("\$jsp.related.${artifactId}.Sample.welcome")</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm using #set( $startbrace = "${" )
  #set( $endbrace = "}" )
  <div class="title">${startbrace}res.content.global.${artifactId}.Sample.welcome${endbrace}</div>